# issues in Signing a jar in java : public key issue

Tags: jnlp, executable-jar, keytool, jarsigner, code-signing-certificate

I am working on one swing application and i want to make it "web start" for that i need to sign my jar

For this, I followed following steps :
1. Create a key store file using following command

```
keytool -genkey -keystore myKeystore -alias myself 

keytool -selfcert -alias myself -keystore myKeystore
```

Enter keystore password:

```
keytool -list -keystore myKeystore
```

Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

myself, Aug 7, 2013, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 9A:CD:47:D2:9D:51:F4:5A:56:FB:5C:27:7B:E6:03:EE:
65:70:F7:7B

Private Key is genarated above successfully.

2.

jarsigner -keystore myKeystore "C:..\myApp.jar" sourabh
Enter Passphrase for keystore:

jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: sourabh.  sourabh must reference a v
alid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key ce
rtificate chain.

It is showing above error.

**Issue 1:** From where i can get this public key?

I googled it. Information is there for public key but could not get any information about creating. How can we generate it for my application.

**Issue 2 :** If i am moving my application to online server (e.g.  apache derver) do i need to copy keystore file also>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to specify the same alias to the jarsigner tool. You used 'myself' when building the keystore: use that again.
2. Definitely not. It contains your private key. Keep it private.

Comment: Thanks for above solution,I am getting one more issue, when i am launching jnlp file, it is showing "Application is blocked by security settings"..what could be the reason?...I have placed my in e: drive

Comment: Your signing key that you generated is "self-signed".  You'll need to add it to your machine's primary key store, or add your local (or launch) machine to the JRE's "trusted sites" list.